# php preg_match_all avoid quotation mark

Tags: php, regex, binding, moodle, preg-match-all

inside Moodle core, when sending a query to the database there's a call to **preg_match_all** looking for : (colon), in order to find query's parameters.

I have a string (inside " ") composed of digits, a colon and a letter **("102516101:t")**.

Of course it's not impling for a parameter. still the Moodle expects one because of the colon(:).

How can I prevent **preg_match_all** looking inside a Quotation mark?
or has anyone gut another idea?

Comment: A placeholder in quotes shouldn't be read as a placeholder. Can you add your code?

Comment: hei, thanks. this is the sql script:

Comment: hi, thanks. the code is a lot more complicated, but basically it comes to - 'SELECT DISTINCT GM.userid, U.firstname, U.lastname FROM '  .$CFG->dbname . '.mdl_groups G WHERE G.name = "102516101:t"' the call to preg_match_all - '$named_count = preg_match_all('/(?<!:):[a-z][a-z0-9_]*/', $sql, $named_matches);'

Comment: I wouldn't modify a frameworks source code. Per the manual `The single quotes are used for sql strings` so I'd change `"102516101:t"` to `'102516101:t'`.

Comment: I've tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: Can you update the question to show your usage? I think modifying the source code would/will cause issues. You can't be the first one to try to use a colon in a SQL string with Moodle (I'd think).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the comments left above, you should explicity specify the variables used in your SQL statement. In other words you should not be constructing your SQL statement by hand, or the minimum required.

Example:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM {groups} WHERE name = :name";
$params = array('name' => '102516101:t');
$DB->execute($sql, $params);
```

You'll also note that table names are specified like this: `{table_name}`, they are automatically expanded with the right prefix.

Comment: No problem! Could you please flag this response as selected answer?